# Accessing records from a different AppleID in CloudKit dashboard

Tags: cloudkit, apple-id

I have two AppleIDs - one for my individual ADC developer program (ADC AppleID) and one used for my devices (Device AppleID). Now I want to add CloudKit to one of my apps and see / debug the CK data from my "Device" AppleID in the CloudKit dashboard. I need to test with the Device AppleID as it contains also a big photos library as sample data.

I added my device AppleID as "Developer" to my ADC program - the ADC AppleID is agent, the device AppleID is developer.

When I log to CloudKit dashboard with my Device AppleID I get the error message

"You are not a member of a Developer Team
The Apple ID you are signed in with (....) is not a member of any Developer Teams, which is necessary to get access to a CloudKit Container.

How is it possible to inspect in the ClodKit dashboard the private database of Device AppleID?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You can only use the dashboard to inspect data associated with a developer account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. You just need to go to **App Store Connect** > **Users and Access** and add your other Apple ID as a member of the dev team.

Be sure to give the account enough rights to access the CloudKit Dashboard. Since it’s an Apple ID you own, I suggest making the new account an **Admin**, but I think the **Developer** role will also be able to sign in to the CK Dashboard.

The last thing you have to do is give the new account permission to access the container. This is down inside the **CloudKit Dashboard**. Click on **Container Permissions** and the new account should be listed there. Click the boxes next to the account to grant permissions.

[image]

...and then...

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: I event tried to make the other account Agent but still am not able to login to the CK dashboard :-(

Comment: @Tom_E I forgot to also mention that you have to add the user in your CloudKit container permissions. I'll update my answer.